# F# - Code improvement

Tags: f#

i'm new to F# and i've come up with a solution to a fairly simple question, which is, given a string of numbers, I need to multiple each digit by two, then get the sum of these digits. For example, the string "123456" should equate to 24

Here is what I was able to come up with

```
let input = "123456"
        |> Seq.map (string >> int)
        |> Seq.map (fun(x) -> x * 2)
        |> Seq.map (int >> string)
        |> String.concat String.Empty
        |> Seq.map (string >> int)
        |> Seq.sum
```

My question is, is there any substantial changes I could make, to make my solution more condensed and more efficient? Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: From your problem description, I don't see why you would need lines 4-6 which convert ints to string to ints. After you have doubled the numbers you only need to sum.

Comment: @LeafGarland because the requirement is to sum the *digits* of the doubled numbers.  That is, `2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + (1 + 0) + (1 + 2) = 24`  Without lines 4-6, the result is 42, not 24.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can compact your code by applying some properties.

`fun x -> x * 2`  is

`fun x -> (*) x 2`  (operator as a function)

`fun x -> (*) 2 x`  (commutative)

`(*) 2`  (eta-reduction)

`map` composition is the same as the composition of the functions to map, your first 3 maps could be written as:

```
Seq.map (string >> int >> (*) 2 >> string)
```

`map` and then `concat` is `collect`

`map` and then `sum` is `sumBy`

So your code could be:

```
"123456"
    |> String.collect (string >> int >> (*) 2 >> string)
    |> Seq.sumBy (string >> int)
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this might be a toy example, but I think that it is actually quite hard to write it in a readable way. I had to run your code line-by-line before I actually understood what is going on!

You can definitely contract it into quite short expression using point-free style (as Gustavo's answer shows), but I would probably not go that far - because you might need to be able to read & understand the code later!

An alternative way would be to use sequence expressions and write something like this:

```
[ for c in "123456" do
    // Get the number, multiply it & yield its characters
    let number = int (string c)
    yield! string (number * 2) ]
// Sum the numbers (converting char to int via a string)
|> Seq.sumBy (string >> int)
```

This is a bit shorter than your original version, but it is still (I think) fairly understandable.

Comment: Char.GetNumericValue: friends don't let friends convert chars to ints via strings.  :)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of efficiency, instead of converting each character in the string into a string in its own right just so you can then convert it to an int...

```
|> Seq.map (string >> int)
```

I would convert the character directly to a number:

```
|> Seq.map (Char.GetNumericValue >> int)
```

This results in less garbage to collect, and although I haven't benchmarked it, I would expect it to be faster.

Answer (score -1):

Like Tomas commented I've not considered the digit-requirement in my original post. So heres my corrected version:

```
"123456"
  |> Seq.map    (string >> int)        // Convert to int sequence
  |> Seq.collect(fun x -> string(x*2)) // Perform multiplication, 
                                       // convert to string and collect the digits as chars
  |> Seq.sumBy  (string >> int)        // Convert the chars to string and than to integer 
                                       // to sum them correctly
```

It is more or less the same what Gustavo posted.

Comment: But your code is doing something else :-) The OP's version does not add the values multiplied by two, but instead their *digits*.